# Deletar posição de array

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Boa tarde

Tenho um app de pedidos, registro os itens dentro de um array
quando preciso deletar um item do pedido, de alguma forma o tamanho do array não diminui
por exemplo cadastrei 3 itens e exclui um, o tamanho do array ainda fica 3 e se eu não adicionar mais um item pra completar, o app trava.

já tentei algumas coisas:

int size = pedido.itens().size -1;

pedidoList.remove(lastindex)

Continua dando problemas. o que poderia ser?

Comment: ```pedido.itens()``` e ```pedidoList``` referenciam o mesmo objeto?

Comment: Olá! pedido.itens é uma instâcia da classe pedidos que acessa o atributo itens que é o arraylist. pedidoList é um outro arrayList da classe Pedidos que eu uso pra listar os pedidos no recycler view. não sei se deu pra entender...

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Acontece que você coloca o valor atual da quantidade de pedidos dentro da variável  `size` e após isso, ela não é alterada, para corrigir, você pode chamar ele novamente:

```java
int size = pedido.itens().size -1;

pedidoList.remove(lastindex);

size = pedido.itens().size -1;
```

Mas, desta forma que está, você poderia criar o `size` após remover o item, já que você não utiliza a variável `size` antes de chamar o método `remove`.

Comment: Boa noite. Me desculpe, não entendi muito bem! eu poderia usar dessa forma? de diminuir menos 1 do tamanho do array mas teria que chamar depois de remover o item, certo?